# PHP: fopen vs streams

Tags: php, http, stream, fopen

Site running PHP 5.3, which has the "streams" extension built-in, but it doesn't appear in the extension list, so I guess it cannot be disabled.

"allow url fopen" is disabled, so I cannot use fopen to make external requests.

However I still can use "streams" to do so (stream_socket_client / fwrite / stream_get_contents).

Is this normal? There is no way to disable "streams" ?

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/stream.installation.php):
Streams are an integral part of PHP as of version 4.3.0. No steps are required to enable them.

Answer (score 1):

> There is no way to disable "streams" ?

If this is the crux of your Q then, yes someone could probably disable stream related functions by adding them to the php.ini directive `disable_functions`.

If its getting around allow_url_fopen you are after, then most people seem to use cURL, see if that is activated in your phpinfo() readout.